# Preload a couple of models to the result of Repo.all

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a function from a third-party library which returns data from a db:

```
cars = get_all_cars #third-party function
```

Internally it does something like `Repo.all(from c in Car)`. I want to preload 2 models associated with the model Car. I could do this

```
`Repo.all(from c in Car, preload: [:driver, :driver_to_car])`
```

but I don't have access and don't want to change the source code of `get_all_cars`. How can I do this then?

Note that Car and Driver has many to many relationship.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a struct or list of structs to `Repo.preload/3`:

```
cars = get_all_cars |> Repo.preload([:driver, :driver_to_car])
```

This would function identical to your example code.

Comment: how can I access `driver_to_car` model from a single `car`?

Comment: The same way as you were doing with `Repo.all(from c in Car, preload: [:driver, :driver_to_car])`. Was that code not working? Can you include the model schema for all 3 models in the question in that case?

Comment: I mean, access or refer, not retrieve. it's already retrieved by the code above.

Comment: Just `car.driver_to_car` should work if that's the association name. You can also see the field names by just inspecting the return value.